# POST Request Doesn't work with Payload But work fine with query string parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, web, asp.net-web-api

I have web api for POST request from http web client(c#).I am using chrome's REST console to debug my web api.
When i passed the parameter in querystring it work fine but when i passed parameter as Raw Body it didn't work.
I don't know what i am missing.

Below is my code.

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public  JsonResult VerifyUserAuth([Bind(Prefix = "t"), Required] string token,
                                         [Bind(Prefix = "ApplicationGUID"), Required] string applicationGUID,
                                         string userID,
                                         string password)
        {
            return Json(NotificationsSecurity.VerifyUserAuth(_connectionstring, userID, password),
                        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

When i debug it in VS debugger and pass parameter as RAW body it show me null. But when i pass as query string i am receiving all parameters right.

Comment: Posting your client code might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web API does not use a formatter by default when you specify multiple simple types. A formatter knows how to map the body payload into an object instance representing a model. For simple types, model binders are mostly used against the URI and RouteData arguments. I would make a small change to your action to correctly parse the payload.

```
public class VerifyUserAuthModel
{
  public string Token { get; set; }
  public string ApplicationGUID { get; set; }
  public string UserID { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
}



public  JsonResult VerifyUserAuth(VerifyUserAuthModel model)
{
}
```

Comment: i did. i am new to this site. i checked yes check mark on left side of your comment.